# Underscore.js - foldl with intersection

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, fold

I have an arbitrary length array of arrays. I want to compute the intersection.

I tried doing this in two ways that I thought were equivalent, but they produced different output.

What is the difference between:

```
var a = [[1,2,3,4,5], [3, 4,5,6,7], [4,5,6,7,8]]
_.foldl(a, function(a, b) { return _.intersection(a, b) } )
// Works as expected -> [4, 5]
```

And this:

```
var a = [[1,2,3,4,5], [4,5,6,7], [5,6,7,8]]
_.foldl(a, _.intersection )
// Does not work -> []
```

?

And is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I am now aware that _.intersection.apply is a better way to do this, but I'm still curious - what is the difference between my two implementations using foldl?

Comment: I'm not sure why the second one won't work. I tried `var func = function(a, b) { return _.intersection(a, b) }` and call `_.foldl(a, func)`, and it works. I think that the problem might be that `_.intersection` doesn't know which arguments to take, so it uses all four provided by the `_.reduce`(memo, value, index, list), and the list makes it not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do it would be using `apply` and `intersection`:

```
var a = [[1,2,3,4,5], [3, 4,5,6,7], [4,5,6,7,8]];
_.intersection.apply(null, a);
// -> returns [ 4, 5 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a fold here.

Underscore's [intersection](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection) already can take multiple arrays.

so `_.intersection.apply(null, a)`

or `_.intersection([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8])`

will work.

Answer (score 2):

`_.intersection` takes any number of arrays.

Simply use

```
_.intersection(arrayA, arrayB, arrayC, ...);
```

Or if you have an array of arrays

```
_.intersection.apply(_, arrayOfArrays);
```

Comment: I don't know how many arrays I have in advance, so I can't use the first form, but the second works for me. Thanks.